# Set formatter for logger in python, not for handler

Tags: python, logging

I always wonder why using dict config in Python I can't set formatter per logger basis, not per handler?

If I have following config:

```py
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s'
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'stdout': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
    },
}
```

Why I can't set set one logger log verbose in console and another log simple in console? I want to do it like this:

```py
'app.booking': {
    'handlers': ['stdout'],
    'formatter': 'simple'
},
'app.management': {
    'handlers': ['stdout'],
    'formatter': 'verbose'
},
```

I don't want to write two different handlers because both apps are using **the same** handler - console.

Am I missing something? Is there any solution for this simple need?

Comment: You are correct that this is not how the logging module works. "both apps are using the same handler - console" that's not quite correct; the formatter is a property of the handler, so you by definition want two different handlers. Why is creating two handlers, each with different formatters, an issue? Semantically a handler *handles* the logs, and formatting is part of handling.

Comment: The reason it works this way is that, if I create a logger, you aren't bound to the way I want to format things. You can hook in with your handler, and handle logs however you want, regardless of how I format them.